# MIPS Overflow check

Tags: overflow, mips, 32-bit, system-calls

I am writing mips code in MARS that uses system call code 5 to read an integer.

Is there a way to verify that the integer input is within the 32-bit range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you allow both positive and negative integers, there is no way to verify that the integer input is within the 32-bit range, since the MARS syscall does not appear to return any error status.